# Is there any way to inspect ::first-line and ::first-letter pseudo-elements in developer tools?

Tags: css, developer-tools

The [`::first-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line) and [`::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) pseudo-elements, as their names suggest, allow you to style the first letter and first line of an HTML element.

However, I can't find any way to inspect these styles in a browser's developer tools. Other pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes (like `::before`, `::after`, `:first-child`, etc) are readily inspectable in dev tools via "Inspect element", but I can't find a way to inspect `::first-letter` or `::first-line`. Is there a way that I'm missing, or is this not currently possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1. Firefox (64 and Nightly)** I was able to easily see both `::first-line` and `::first-letter` pseudo-elements in the Firefox inspector:

[image].

You can see those styles in your inspector by expanding the 'pseudo-elements' tab:
[image]

**2. Chrome (72)** I have no trouble seeing it in the Chrome inspector either (applies to both `::first-line` and `::first-letter`):

[image]

Was not able to find the pseudo-element in Safari.

Answer (score 4):

In Chrome (74), I see these styles listed all the way at the bottom of the styles list, past the `Inherited from` blocks:
[image: chrome inspector pseudo classes]

Answer (score -1):

Yes by clicking the add button("+" (Insert Style Rule Below)) [See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZz1o.png)

```
div::first-line {
 // enter code here
}
```

or

```
div::first-letter {
// enter code here
}
```

Comment: The question asks about inspecting pseudo-elements, but it appears your answer refers to _creating styles_ for psuedo-elements.